# Searching Word in String after webscraping

Tags: python, string, search, web-crawler

so my problem is that I'm not really into programming, the only thing I do is making websites and selling them.

I learned a little bit of python but not much and here is where my problem comes in. I startet a program because I want to learn the language while it is usefull... So as I said early I sell websites and there is a website in my country where almost every company is listed. I want a **scraper** that looks for all the Number on the website.

Currently it only works for the first number but every on every page only ten are listed, here is my code:

from requests import get

def starting():

```
keyword = input("Suchbegriff: ")
URL = "https://www.herold.at/gelbe-seiten/" + keyword + "/"
print("Targing... : " + URL)
data = get(URL)
print(data.text[:100000000000000000000000])
    
tel = data.text.find('"tel:')

print(tel)
print(data.text[tel:tel + 19])
```

starting()

Currently if I enter a branche niche name like "friseur" i get only the first number as output:

"39820
"tel:+4315124367" t"

How can I make it that the crawler continues and gets the other 9.

Already thanks for your anwsers!

Comment: find is a method of the string class which return only the 1st occurrence of what you are looking for

Comment: so what can i do, that it catches all 10?

Comment: maybe smt like `for line in data.text.split('\n'): if line.find('"tel:') > -1: ...`  otherwise you can use module such `bs4` to scrap the content of the page or use regex

Comment: okay thanks, I'll try bs4

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To get the number you can use the build-in module `re` (which stands for *regex* shorthand for regular expressions). The parameter `flags=re.M` stands for multi-line, so it applies the pattern to the full string, without only till the end of the line.

```
import re
import requests

url = # see above
response = request.get(url)

tel_nrs = re.search(r'(\+\d+)', response.text, flags=re.M)

print(tel_nrs.groups())
```

Output

```
+4315124367
...
```

**Remark**: also if you use `bs4` you will have to face this problem, `bs4` is useful to navigate the page

Together with `bs4` could be

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

url = # see above
response = request.get(url)

# make the response a "navigable" object
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

# regex pattern for the tel nr
n_teL_pattern = re.compile(r'(\+\d+)')

# look for all string in the soup which satisfy the pattern
for s in soup.find_all(string=n_teL_pattern):
    print(n_teL_pattern.search(s).group())   # print the match
```

Comment: `lxml` is the parser that I normally used but it is not from the standard library. There is one from the standard library `html.parser`, so no extra installation. check the docs for more details https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser